# Looking for Google API to pull near by locations, facilities based on Pincode

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can anybody help me with a Google API which get me all surrounding information based on Pincode as an input.

Basically, if I input Pincode number then API should return all shopping malls, bridges, hospitals, hotels etc. I want to be able to store these information in database.

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I hope following code will help you. What it does? 1. Take your pincode from input field, geocode it. 2. From the result of geocode, it applies on places api to find nearby stores in 500 meter radius.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Geocoding service</title>
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 800px;
    widows: 700px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
  #panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -180px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 8,
center: latlng
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
function codeAddress() {
var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: results[0].geometry.location
  });

  var request = {
     location: results[0].geometry.location,
     radius: '500',
     types: ['store']
   }; //500 meters and stores only

   var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
   service.nearbySearch(request, callback);


} else {
  alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
}});}
function callback(results, status) {
console.log(status, results);
if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  var place = results[i];
  //createMarker(results[i]);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map:map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  })
}}}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="panel">
  <input id="address" type="textbox" value="452009">
  <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div></body></html>
```

If you have any more queries, please comment, we can work on it.

Regards,

Suyash

Comment: Thanks Suyash. Let me try this out and i will get back to you for questions. .